# Best way to apply a transform to every element in a list at the same time in Kotlin

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin

Basically I'm trying to apply a long-running transformation to a list of elements in Kotlin. Right now I'm using the .map function, but this causes all of the transformations to run serially, when I need them to run simultaneously because of time.

Here's how it works now:

```
async {
    val list = await { list.execute().items.map { initialValue ->
        getResultAfterALongTime(initialValue)
    }}
    onCompletion(list)
}
```

As I explained, the function .map runs the transformation and then waits for it to finish before preceding to the next element. How should I alter this to allow the transformations to run concurrently and the proced when they're all finished?

Comment: What are the async/await calls? Which async library is it?

Comment: @voddan kotlinx.coroutines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parallelStream` should help.

```
async {
    val list = await { list.execute().items.parallelStream().map { initialValue ->
        getResultAfterALongTime(initialValue)
    }}
    onCompletion(list)
}
```